# centered DIV not showing fully in small resolutions,

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In small resolution like 540x960 and 960x540 my page has weird behavior. These resolutions aren't supposed to be fully responsive, they have to be scrolled up/down or left/right to see full content. Problem is with centered DIV.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="age-warning-content">

  ....


</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.age-warning-content {

  background:white !important;  
  width:630px;
  height:550px;     
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

It crops part of centered DIV like this:

- If 540x960 then left part is cropped (not visible). It is available to scroll to right side for content, but can't scroll to the left to see that part.
  [image]
- If 960x540 then top part is cropped (not visible)

[image]

Top part I fixed with responsive css. But I didn't work on left side.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 779px) {
    .age-warning-content {


        margin-top: 90px;


    }

}
```

**Problem**: Centered DIV not fully visible in small resolutions. Problem occurs on pc and on Iphone 6 screens.

Answer (score 0):

that's because you apply width which is larger than respective screen size

if possible you can apply `max-width:630px;  width: 80%;` and `max-height:550px; height: 80%;`

like I did here

```
.age-warning-content {
  background:white !important;  
  max-width:630px;
  width: 80%;
  max-height:550px;     
  height: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p9o47gxc/1/)

Comment: Thanks for try but, I can't reduce size of that div. It should just be scrollable to the left as far as to see full div content.

Comment: I tested your code :  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwneKwDsKmarRGNoTWJIUTktTHc/view